# R: Computing monthly averages from hourly data and then plotting

Tags: r

After converting a date/time character string into POSIXlt using strptime, I am left with the following (data truncated for ease here):

> ```
>          DateTime  North  South   West   East  Seast  System
> ```
>
> 1 2008-09-12 01:00:00 1919.9 3721.4 2085.9 2565.5 2571.1 12863.8
>
> 2 2008-09-12 02:00:00 1827.0 3518.1 1965.3 2396.9 2410.7 12118.0
>
> 3 2008-09-12 03:00:00 1755.4 3388.4 1866.8 2338.7 2335.2 11684.5
>
> 4 2008-09-12 04:00:00 1733.5 3327.1 1810.0 2295.6 2290.2 11456.4
>
> 5 2008-09-12 05:00:00 1742.7 3327.3 1831.4 2314.2 2302.3 11517.9
>
> 6 2008-09-12 06:00:00 1912.2 3504.4 1986.7 2515.0 2502.6 12420.9

I then have aggregated the data (seemingly right) into year-month averages using the following snippet of code:
`North_Monthly_Avg <- aggregate(North, list(Date=format(DateTime, "%Y-%m")),mean)`
which yields the following:

> ```
>  Date        x
> ```
>
> 1 2008-09 2192.066
>
> 2 2008-10 1885.074
>
> 3 2008-11 1675.373
>
> 4 2008-12 1637.231
>
> 5 2009-01 1752.693
>
> 6 2009-02 1743.393

I can plot the 'x' values but cannot get the year-months to label properly on the x-axis since it is only plotting the index.  Not sure what I am missing...I have played around with axis.POSIXct, but have no luck.

Comment: Is the `Date` column a date class, or just a factor/character?

Comment: Date class (POSIXlt) after I converted it from factor

Comment: Actually, I should say that 'DateTime' is a date class...'Date' in the aggregate output has a class of NULL...how do I get that into a date class?

Comment: I think after using `format` it will become a character class again. To convert to a date class I think you will need to add a day to the string too.

Comment: Instead of using `format()` with aggregate, consider using `cut` (`cut.Date`) -- `cut(DateTime, "month")` will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `zoo` and `lattice`:

```
library(zoo)
library(lattice)

dat <- 'Date  Time  North  South   West   East  Seast  System
2008-09-12 01:00:00 1919.9 3721.4 2085.9 2565.5 2571.1 12863.8
2008-09-12 02:00:00 1827.0 3518.1 1965.3 2396.9 2410.7 12118.0
2008-09-12 03:00:00 1755.4 3388.4 1866.8 2338.7 2335.2 11684.5
2008-09-12 04:00:00 1733.5 3327.1 1810.0 2295.6 2290.2 11456.4
2008-09-12 05:00:00 1742.7 3327.3 1831.4 2314.2 2302.3 11517.9
2008-09-12 06:00:00 1912.2 3504.4 1986.7 2515.0 2502.6 12420.9'

z <- read.zoo(text = dat,  header = TRUE,  index.column = 1:2, tz = "")
xyplot(z)

zAgg <- aggregate(z$North,  by = as.yearmon,  FUN = mean)

dat2 <- 'Date        x
2008-09 2192.066
2008-10 1885.074
2008-11 1675.373
2008-12 1637.231
2009-01 1752.693
2009-02 1743.393'

zAgg <- read.zoo(text = dat2, header = TRUE,  FUN = as.yearmon)

plot(zAgg, xaxt = "n")

tt <- time(zAgg)
m <- format(tt, "%m")
axis(side = 1, at = tt, labels = ifelse(m == "01", trunc(tt), m), cex.axis = .7)
```

Comment: This is kind of what I already done but without zoo...even if i take your code i dont get plausible month-year tick marks concurrent with the data points

Comment: @user1062431.  Try converting the index to `Date` class for plotting or produce a custom axis. There is an example of using a custom axis in the help file `?xyplot.zoo` .  Also see `?panel.axis`  Another thing to try is classic graphics.  Just replace `xyplot` with `plot`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **as.integer()** on the date

```
North_Monthly_Avg <- aggregate(North, list(Date=as.integer(format(DateTime, "%Y-%m"))),mean)
```

Comment: When I try that I get the following:                           Warning message:
In aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 0):

@user1062431,
To edit the tick names to your preferred format, edit the m <- format(tt, "%m") line in the answer of Oscar.

To get the format  12 - 2008 you need to modify:

m <- format(tt, "%m") to  m <- format(tt, "%m - %Y")

To get the format dec 2008 you need to modify:

m <- format(tt, "%m") to  m <- format(tt, "%b %Y")

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there is no date.  You will have to settle with a 1st of the month or 15th of the month and apply that to your aggregated table.

I came up with this:

```
North_Monthly_Avg=aggregate(North,by=list(format(DateTime,'%Y-%m')),mean)
names(North_Monthly_Avg)=c('Month','North')
North_Monthly_Avg$day=15
North_Monthly_Avg$Date=paste(North_Monthly_Avg$Month,North_Monthly_Avg$day,sep='-')
North_Monthly_Avg$Date=strptime(North_Monthly_Avg$Date,'%Y-%m-%d')
plot(m$Date,m$North,xaxt='n') # the xaxt='n' removes any ticks on the x axis
axis(1,as.numeric(m$Date),labels=format(m$Date,'%Y-%m')) # formats the x axis to your liking
```

I am fairly new to R, so this may not be the most elegant solution, but it will work.

Replace the 15 with 1 in the `$day` line if you prefer 1st of the month and the `sep` in `paste` should be changed to `'-0'`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is because you are using `format` to create the groupings to use for the subdivision.  This makes the values into strings, so that plotting functions don't know to plot them like dates.

The `cut` function has a `cut.POSIXlt` variant that will do exactly what you need, and preserve the type information so that all the plotting stuff will just work.

Instead of

```
North_Monthly_Avg <- aggregate(North, list(Date=format(DateTime, "%Y-%m")),mean)
```

Just use

```
North_Monthly_Avg <- aggregate(North, cut(DateTime, "month"), mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could can try the package `openair` and use it's function `timeAverage`

Hourly to monthly

```
library(openair)  
mydata$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(mydata$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT"))
hourly<-timeAverage(mydata, average.time = "day")
```