# How to write a for loop to calculate using a math equation in R?

Tags: r, math, for-loop, plyr

in R, I would like to find a way to write a for loop using the following math equation and a .csv file.

Here is an example showing two rows in a .csv file.

```
6/27/2010 8:45  131.04
6/27/2010 9:00  111.11
```

The second column would be `x` in the following equation.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/inOKV.jpg]

I need help writing the equation above and a for loop that writes .csv file with load variability.

Comment: Can you read your csv into R, like with `X=read.csv("pathtofile")`. If so, can you add dput(head(X)) to your question?

Comment: Yes, I have the code, but did want to post because I know that it is completely wrong. What does dput(head(X)) do? I searched and it is for  a debian package upload tool? I am confused.

Comment: `dput` is an R function, as is `head`. Use `?function_name` to get the documentation of that function, e.g. `?head`.

Answer (score 4):

To get the L_var for a certain set of numbers I believe this would work:

```
l_var = sd(x) / mean(x)
```

where `x` is the vector of numbers. Next we wrap it in a function:

```
l_var = function(x) sd(x) / mean(x)
outcome = l_var(input)
```

where `input` is a vector of numbers, and `outcome` the outcome of the math equation.

If your timestamp column is of class `POSIXlt`, you can use `strftime` to create a factor column where you categorize your data. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007877/calculating-hourly-averages-from-a-multi-year-timeseries/10008233#10008233) for more details on this step. Next you can use `ddply` from the `plyr` package to get the `l_var` per category (say a day):

```
result = ddply(df, .(cat), summarise, l_var = l_var(value))
```

where `df` is the input data.frame where `cat` is the time category, and value the `x` value in your equation above. To write the result to file you can use `write.csv`:

```
write.csv(result, file = "out.csv")
```

I think this covers about all the steps...

Comment: You might want to add `na.rm=TRUE` to sd() and mean() or some other method for addressing missing values.

Comment: I'm a bit worried that there is no consideration for the 15 minute period in this solution. I would have thought that a `zoo:rollapply` approach would have been needed.

Comment: I agree with @DWin, I do not have much experience with zoo. Could you provide an example @DWin?

Comment: If the questioner decides that his data needs to have a rolling average or an aggregation step, which I am still unclear about, he should first do a search: [r] rolling average ... or perhaps: [r] aggregate interval

Comment: Can you explain how to wrap it in a function? It did not work. Also i need to get a sd by taking the difference b/w lines and don't I need to write a for loop for that?

Comment: I wrapped the calculation in your equation in a function, what did not work? Your equation does not include any difference between lines, so please specify your question more accurately. What do you want to do.

Comment: I have 860 rows that have two columns. The first column is composed of timestamps in 15 minute interval and the second column- load (kw). I need to get load variability in 15 minute interval using the equation I posted in my question. Is that pretty clear?

Comment: Please provide the new information as an edit to your question. Ain addition, provide us with a reproducible example.

Comment: I believe I have already done that. Can you clarify what you mean by a reproducible example?

Comment: Reproducible in the sense that it is a piece of R code which reproduces your problem and situation, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.